# How to do SELECT TOP @Param in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do the following in a proc, but getting an incorrect syntax error:

```
SELECT TOP @NumberOfResultsToReturn *
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Add parenthesis:

```
SELECT TOP (@NumberOfResultsToReturn) *
```

Comment: Cool I learned something new myself, I would have thought it would require dynamic sql

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server: Put the argument in parens:

```
SELECT TOP (@NumberOfResultsToReturn) *
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I was doing it in the old times:

```
SET @@ROWCOUNT = @NumberOfResultsToReturn
SELECT ........
SET @@ROWCOUNT = 0
```

This will work, although `SELECT TOP (@NumberOfResultsToReturn)` is preferable if you're using SQL server that supports this syntax:

Answer (score 1):

This is supported in SQL Server 2005 and later, but not in SQL Server 2000.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use the RowNumber() method instead.

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @PageNum AS INT;
DECLARE @PageSize AS INT;
SET @PageNum = 2;
SET @PageSize = 10;

WITH OrdersRN AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate, OrderID) AS RowNum
          ,OrderID
          ,OrderDate
          ,CustomerID
          ,EmployeeID
      FROM dbo.Orders
)

SELECT * 
  FROM OrdersRN
 WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1 
                  AND @PageNum * @PageSize
 ORDER BY OrderDate
         ,OrderID;
```

**EDIT** Or you could use parentheses...which I was unaware of at the time :) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do this in SQL 2000, but you can try to construct the query

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(500)
set @query = 'SELECT TOP ' + @NumberOfResultsToReturn + '* FROM table'
EXEC @query
```

I didn't know the parenthesis trick for SQL 2005, thanks too guys, !!!